# Check if part of multidimensional array is null before assigning

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an preview page in HTML which displays the data from an API call (`multidimensional array`).

I want to display this array data into a `<table>`. Before doing this i need to check a few parameters to enhance the readability, for this i use the function `setFeature()`.

**Issue:**

The multidimensional array does not always have all option fields available. For example in the preview below you can see that `optiond` from `selectA` is **null**. When `optiond` is **not null** it will hold multiple sub values, like you can see in `selectB`.

When trying to pass `databank[0]['selectA']['optiond']['suba']` to the function `setFeature()`. The error `TypeError: databank[0].selectA.optiond is null"` will display.

**What i have tried:**

```
// Checking the variable "suba" before passing to the function "setFeature()"
var suba = databank[0]['selectA']['optiond']['suba']; // added into variable for enhanced readability.
preview += (suba !== null) ? setFeature('D', suba) : '';
```

This works without error's (*)

```
var optiond = databank[0]['selectA']['optiond'];
if (optiond !== null) {
    setFeature('D', databank[0]['selectA']['optiond']['suba']) 
}
```

**Question:**

I am looking for the **shortest way** to ignore the value when its null, without creating an overload of coding lines.

(*) Using this method (*checking if parent is not null*) will cause an overload of coding lines because the multi dimensional array is huge and i only need 15% of the array information to be displayed to the customers.

**Code snippet:**

```js
var databank = [{
  "selectA": {
    "optiona": "Some string information",
    "optionb": true,
    "optionc": false,
    "optiond": null,
    "optione": "Courant",
  },
  "selectB": {
    "optiona": "Some string information",
    "optionb": true,
    "optionc": true,
    "optiond": {
      "suba": 30.0,
      "subb": 10.0,
      "subc": 10.0,
      "subd": null
    },
    "optione": "Courant",
  }
}];

var preview;
preview += setFeature('A', databank[0]['selectA']['optiona']);
preview += setFeature('B', databank[0]['selectA']['optionb']);
preview += setFeature('C', databank[0]['selectA']['optionc']);
preview += setFeature('D', databank[0]['selectA']['optiond']['suba']);
preview += setFeature('E', databank[0]['selectA']['optione']);
$('#test').append(preview);

function setFeature(name, data) {
  if (data !== null && data !== undefined && data.toString().toLowerCase() !== 'onbekend') {
    console.log('PASSED: ' + name + ': ' + data + ', length: ' + data.length);
    if (typeof data === "boolean") {
      if (data === true) {
        return '<tr><th scope="row">' + name + '</th><td>Yes</td></tr>';
      } else {
        return '<tr><th scope="row">' + name + '</th><td>No</td></tr>';
      }
    } else {
      return '<tr><th scope="row">' + name + '</th><td>' + data + '</td></tr>';
    }
  } else {
    return '';
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="test"></table>
```

Comment: Using the [Optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining), you could write this as `databank[0]['selectA']['optiond']?.suba`. That returns `undefined` for properties that do not exist, so the `data !== null` check would need to be modified accordingly, otherwise `data.toLowerCase` will fail on `undefined` next.

Comment: Also `toLowerCase()` is missing `()` to call it

Comment: @CBroe your comment should be an answer. Your comment is the shortest possible way as far as I know. Added a check for variable equal to undefined to my function setFeature() to handle your code. 
@charlietfl thank you for point out the missing `()`

Comment: Be aware of the limited support and the draft status of the operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [Optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining), you could write this as

```
databank[0]['selectA']['optiond']?.suba
```

That returns `undefined` for properties that do not exist, so the `data !== null` check would need to be modified accordingly, otherwise `data.toLowerCase()` will fail on undefined next.

The operator only works with the dot notation of accessing properties, not with `['suba']`. But since it doesn’t look like you need any kind of dynamic solution here (where `foo[variable]` would be used, which can’t be substituted by `foo.variable` the same way), that should not be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it won't look pretty either way, as you can't nest into an array if it's undefined part way through.

```
if (ArrayTest === undefined) return;
if (ArrayTest["test"] === undefined) return;
if (ArrayTest["test"]["test"] === undefined) return;
```

There's some ways you can make this look better though,

```js
Object = {
  tester:()=>{
    console.log("works");
  }
};
let type = "tester";
if (typeof Object[type] === "function") {
  Object[type]();
}
```

You can run the ugly try-catch on your call

```js
    try{
       console.log(TestArray["test"]["test"].testvalue);
    }catch(e){
       console.log("no such variable");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var databank = [{
  "selectA": {
    "optiona": "Some string information",
    "optionb": true,
    "optionc": false,
    "optiond": null,
    "optione": "Courant",
  },
  "selectB": {
    "optiona": "Some string information",
    "optionb": true,
    "optionc": true,
    "optiond": {
      "suba": 30.0,
      "subb": 10.0,
      "subc": 10.0,
      "subd": null
    },
    "optione": "Courant",
  }
}];

const get = (o, ...path) => o!= null && path.length ? get(o[path.shift()],...path) : o;

for(const select of ['selectA','selectB']) {
  let preview = setFeature('A', get(databank,0,select,'optiona'));
  preview += setFeature('B', get(databank,0,select,'optionb'));
  preview += setFeature('C', get(databank,0,select,'optionc'));
  preview += setFeature('D', get(databank,0,select,'optiond', 'suba'));
  preview += setFeature('E', get(databank,0,select,'optione'));
  $('#test').append(preview);
}
function setFeature(name, data) {
  if (data != null && data.toLowerCase != 'onbekend') {
    console.log('PASSED: ' + name + ': ' + data + ', length: ' + data.length);
    if (typeof data === "boolean") {
      if (data === true) {
        return '<tr><th scope="row">' + name + '</th><td>Yes</td></tr>';
      } else {
        return '<tr><th scope="row">' + name + '</th><td>No</td></tr>';
      }
    } else {
      return '<tr><th scope="row">' + name + '</th><td>' + data + '</td></tr>';
    }
  } else {
    return '';
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="test"></table>
```